# Not able to access .net 5.0 docker container at http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html

Tags: .net, docker, devops

i have written a docker file to containerise .net 5.0 Web API. i am able to create image. i am also able to push all the dll files to root folder of container (verified on container bash termonal) however i am not able to access http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html.

from container bash terminal when i tried to run dotnet Summit.API.dll. i am getting below error

**Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.**

My docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app   
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj", "API/WebUI/"]
COPY ["Application/Summit.Application.csproj", "Application/"]
COPY ["Domain/Shared/Summit.Domain.csproj", "Domain/Shared/"]
COPY ["Domain/SqlKata.Execution/SqlKata.Execution.csproj", "Domain/SqlKata.Execution/"]
COPY ["Domain/QueryBuilder/QueryBuilder.csproj", "Domain/QueryBuilder/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Summit.Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/WebUI/Summit.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Summit.API.csproj" -c Release

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/API/WebUI/bin/Release/net5.0/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Summit.API.dll"]
```

To create container from image i am using command

```
docker container run -itd -p 8000:5000 imageid
```

please help me out here

Comment: You say you try to access `http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html`. Since you map the port to 8000 on the host, it should be `http://localhost:8000/swagger/index.html`

Comment: either of them is not working. actually on the vm where container is running i was trying http://localhost:8000/swagger not able to access.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
(...)
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
```

ENV vars and ARG are scoped per build-stage: you defined these variables for your `base` layer of container but you are running your app from `runtime` layer where these ENV are not set.

(actually, using staged build is great and you are doing it almost right!)

Thats why kestrel is trying to bind to "default" (127.0.0.1 - and thats localhost/loopback address **'inside your container'** not 'your localhost' nor 'virtual machine localhost' - you want Kestrel to bind to 0.0.0.0:port)

(Please note that you can bind Kestrel to standart port :80 (http) and/or :443 (https) and then remap port on docker run with `-p {any}:80`, for example `-p 8080:80` or  `-p 8000:80` or `-p 123456:80`. With this, you will save a little headache to write everywhere 'my container is exposing :5000')

You can test setting correct *runtime* ENV variables with

```
docker container run -itd -p 8000:5000 imageid -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000" ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

---

Also, you are exposing :5000, trying to set _URLS to :5000, re-mapping it to port 8000 (with `-p 8000:5000`) but then you are trying to access it again thru `http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html` - but thats the port INSIDE your container, you remapped it to :8000 with your `docker container run -p 8000:5000`.

You should access your container at `http://localhost:8000/swagger/index.html`

---

Also, you can run docker image right from your Visual Studio with attached debugger.
Not sure how to run single dockerfile, but there is `docker-compose.dcproj` for `docker-compose.yml`.

---

If problem persist, please double check if something isnt already binding to your port :8000 before your container goes up: stop your container and try (powershell)

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "localhost" -Port 8000 -InformationLevel "Detailed"
```

---

AFAIK best aproach:
Do NOT set any ENV in dockerfile "for runtime". If you dont need them for compilation, you dont need them in dockerfile.

Do NOT modify dockerfile generated with Visual Studio. When you (un)reference project, just delete it and generate it again. Your ENV declaration would be lost. Plus, you dont want to push to registry / publish to production your app with `ENVIRONMENT=Development`.

Go and delete explicit bind to 127.0.0.1:5000 from your Program.cs (cant remember where exactly, but it is there somewhere). Instead, set `AllowedHosts=*` in your `applicationSettings.json`. Kestrel will then bind to 0.0.0.0 interface by default.

Do NOT try to run your dockerfile in Development mode from console. Use docker-compose thru [Visual Studio `.dcproj`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools?view=vs-2019) (you will have `docker-compose.yml` where you can set any env variables / volumes / networks etc you want (ready for production*) and `docker-compose.override.yml` where you set your build context / path to dockerfile / your dev variables / volumes etc. When you hit f5 VS will bring up your `docker-compose` and will attach debugger.
Thruth to be told, you rarely do development with only one container (where is, for example, your database? :) )

*: with grain of salt, see Kubernetes etc, but thats different topic.

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation. but still it;s not working and faciing same issue. I can see that AllowHost is Set to AllowedHosts=* and i also tried with  ;;; docker container run -itd -p 8000:5000 imageid -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000" ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
  but no luch\k. still getting same error.

Comment: If the error is still the same, your app is still trying to bind to `localhost` (`loopback`) which is wrong (mainly because its `loopback` of your container, not yours loopback ;) ). Which is strange, because i dont think that error comes from your container (his port :5000 should be free... its container...)

Comment: wait a second -- you are trying to run app _'from container bash terminal'_? But thats wrong because your app is already running: see `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Summit.API.dll"]` in your dockerfile. That means when your container goes up, your summit app is started.

Comment: if app is started, i should be able to access it. from the VM on which my containers are running. but when i try to access the app i am getting error that the site can't be reached.

Any recommendation from you to verify where i am doing the mistake

Comment: ` 
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
[17:59:47 WRN] Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
[17:59:47 WRN] Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
[17:59:47 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
[17:59:47 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[17:59:47 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[17:59:47 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[17:59:47 INF] Content root path: /app
 `

Comment: this is the log from visual studio

Comment: try run this from elevated PowerShell: `netstat -a -b` and look up which process is squating your :5000 (my bet is some forgotten container). Also, are you running your app from docker container or from visual studio? (you wrote that your error message is from VS...)

Comment: i have a ubuntu VM, on that i have install docker and i am building images on that Vm and creating container from same vm. i have only one vm cutrrently

Comment: currently nothing is running on port 5000